# Windows Authentication working on one local machine but not another

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, authentication, iis

We have two development machines(one is my co-worker's machine who recently left the company and the other one is mine), each one running Windows 10, and each has a same version of application file (I've got the same version from the source control).

IIS 7.5 is on a different server and the authentication is set to:

```
Anonymous Authentication Enabled
Windows Authentication Enabled
```

On my co-worker's local machine, the windows authentication is working fine. By "working" I mean that

- `HttpContext.Current.Request.LogonUserIdentity.Name` shows my logon info
- `HttpContext.Current.Request.LogonUserIdentity.IsAuthenticated` = `true`
- `HttpContext.Current.Request.LogonUserIdentity.AuthenticationType` = `Negotiate`

But when I try the same application on my local machine, it's not working.

- `HttpContext.Current.Request.LogonUserIdentity.Name` = `NT AUTHORITY\\IUSR`
- `HttpContext.Current.Request.LogonUserIdentity.IsAuthenticated` = `false`
- `HttpContext.Current.Request.LogonUserIdentity.AuthenticationType` is empty

There's no authentication settings in both web.config.

I also checked `Windows Features` for both machines and made it all the same.

I'd appreciate any help on What else I can check to figure out why windows authentication works on one machine and not another?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not authenticated. Meaning, you are using anonymous authentication in IIS on your machine.

Disallow Anonymous, and any other undesired authentication within IIS settings, and it should work for you.

Comment: Oh... I never looked into the IIS on the local machine. It did work!!